# Веб сокеты linux

Tags: php, linux, websocket

Здравствуйте! Нашёл вот такую штуку как websocketd http://websocketd.com Кто ни будь пользовался? Как правильно установить? В директорию с папкой сайта или не важно? И как потом задать переменную окружения?